# Storing instance of object created under AppDomain

Tags: c#, reflection

Iam trying to use AppDomains in order to isolate and run code in my application.
What I need to do, is to create new AppDomain for each client and under that AppDomain, I need to create instance of another class which contains the code that needs to be isolated. I also need to somehow store that created instance, so that I can access it later when the same client that created it calls again. 
The way Im creating it now is this:

```
private Dictionary<string, IsolatedClass> isolatedClassesList = new Dictionary<string, IsolatedClass>();

public void Initialize(string clientId)
{
    AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New AppDomain");

    IsolatedClass isolatedClass = (IsolatedClass)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(IsolatedClass).FullName);

    isolatedClass.Initialize(clientId);

    isolatedClassesList.Add(clientId, isolatedClass);
}
```

The creation of AppDomain and first call of "`Initiliaze(clientId)`" method works fine. Also storing it in the dictionary (for later use) is done without any exceptions.

The problem occurs when I try to get the instance of previously created `IsolatedClass` later, like that:

```
public void DoSomething (string clientId)
{
    IsolatedClass isolatedClass = isolatedClassesList.First(x => x.Key == clientId).Value;

    isolatedClass.RunIsolatedMethod();
}
```

It throws null refference exception (it cannot retrieve the instance). When I put a breakpoint there and check what is inside the dictionary, for `Value`, it shows me that: "Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context."

Is this totally wrong approach or is there just some minor mistake?
If my approach is totally wrong, is there any other way how to achieve my goal?

---

**EDIT**

Apparently, there was some issue with the `IsolatedClass` itself - it was inheriting from another class which was inheriting from MarshallByRefObject. When I created simple dummy class and procceded with instruction from Kentonbmax, it worked. 
I will continue testing to see, what was the real issue.

Comment: Take a look at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache. You can put your constructed object away in the cache, using a cache key that identifies the both the application domain/clientrequestor and the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and the only difference is that my class is inside of a different library. You can replace IsolatedClass with MarshalByRefObject as your value type in your dictionary if you have different class types you want to interact with.

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(typeof(MyType).Assembly.FullName);

                    var proxy = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                        typeof(MyType).Assembly.FullName,
                        typeof(MyType).FullName) as MyType;
```

UnhandledException and DomainUnload events inside of your IsolatedClass are a good way to dispose of any resources in your IsolatedClass when unloading your AppDomains. Also I recommend using 'as' instead of a direct cast this way you can check to see if the cast failed without throwing an InvalidCast Exception.

Using .First is problematic because you are not guaranteed that the key exists and can therefore get back a null reference. If you know the clientId when you call Initialize why do you not know it when you call DoSomething?

```
if(_isolatedClassesList.ContainsKey(clientId)
{
    MyType mine = _isolatedClassesList[clientId] as MyType;
    mine.MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to switch the value type in dictionary to MarshalByRefObject. Adding to dictionary still works fine, but when trying to retrieve the object using  `IsolatedClass isolatedClass = isolatedClassesList.First(x => x.Key == clientId).Value as IsolatedClass;`  it still throws an null refference exception. I will continue with testing the MemoryCache, as suggested by StingyJack.

Comment: See my revised solution.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still the same. The reason I need to identify it by clientId is that the main class is a WCF service class and thus, many clients can connect to it. The thing is, that Im pretty sure the key is present in the dictionary, I even checked it using breakpoints. The problem is, that the way Im storing `IsolatedClass` instance (or MarshalByRefObject from which my class inherits) is perhaps wrong, cause I can not retrieve the value back.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting - I tried again your way, but this time, I created simple dummy class - the only difference was, that my `IsolatedClass` was inheriting from `WhateverClass`, which was inheriting from MarshallByrRefObject. Now, with the new `DummyClass`, I tried to inherit from MarshalByRefObject directly and it seems to be working. I will procced with testing to identify, whether multi-level inheritance was the real issue or not.

Comment: You should always consider an alternative to multilevel inheritance since it is a direct violation of the 'O' in SOLID.